# slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method

Tags: python, subprocess, glob

Here is the code I have so far: I believe my problem is from the pattern matching. I have tried my best to find answers on here and other sources but it has proven difficult so far. Please help me. Thank you all

```
def newInput(input_dir):
    files = []
    ext = '*[1]\.*txt', '*[2]\.*txt', '*\.csv'
    for ext in ('*\.csv', '*[0-9]\.*txt'):
        files.extend(glob.glob(os.path.join(input_dir, ext)))
        for filenames in files:
            if filenames.endswith('*[1]\.*txt', '*\.csv'):
                subprocess.call([do something using the files])
            elif files.endswith('*[2]\.*txt', '*\.csv'): 
                subprocess.call([do something using the files])
            else:
                print "Specify a correct path to input the files"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    newInput(sys.argv[1])
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. As written, this question isn't really a good fit for StackOverflow. I think you could ask a much better question if you just started writing the code piece by piece and then trying to find answers on each small thing you need to do. Basically, each of your numbered steps is one small piece, and there's a lot out there about how to do each one. The real work here is, "How do you put all these pieces together?" Doing that is a skill you *really* need to acquire for programming.

Comment: Try taking it one step at a time. First create a program that accepts a directory as an argument. (You can just make it `print` the directory path to start with.) Then make it list the files in that directory (or check if particular ones exist if you need specific names). Then make it list the combinations. And so on. On step at a time. Good luck!

Comment: I have come up with something. just not confident enough yet to put it on here

Comment: That's great! If it's working as far as you can tell, then http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ would be the place to ask for advice on improvements. If you don't know if it's working, then I encourage you to test it yourself. =) If it is doing something specific you don't understand, then asking about that particular thing would make a much better question. But this question, as it is now, definitely needs to be narrowed down. Why aren't you confident? If you have questions about particular things, you can ask those. If you're worried it's not good, then everyone went through that period.

Comment: I have edited my question by adding my code. Thank you for your advice

Comment: That helps (and your code isn't bad!), but I still think this question needs narrowing. What *specifically* are you confused about? Maybe a good way to start would be to pick a line or two and make that the focus of your question. If you can't identify anything like that and it seems to work when you try it, then I think Code Review is absolutely where you should be going.

Comment: When I run my code, it gives me this error. TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
 I googled and tried to make amendments but it is not working still. I know it has to do with my pattern matching though..is it not?

Comment: @rose, what are you trying to do as your code logic is hard to follow

Comment: @jpmc26: there is no way; the code works. It is not appropriate to post broken code on codereview.SE

Comment: @rose: provide the full traceback.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Yeah. My comment post-code-addition was probably too hasty. Sorry. I tried to emphasize testing it, though.

Answer (score 1):

[`endswith`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.endswith) does not take the arguments you think it does.

> `str.endswith(suffix[, start[, end]])`
>   Return True if the string ends with the specified suffix, otherwise return False. **suffix can also be a tuple of suffixes to look for**. With optional start, test beginning at that position. With optional end, stop comparing at that position.

---

But also, this code is wrong because:

- `files` gets longer on each iteration, so you check the csv files twice
- `list` objects have no `endswith` member - looks like a typo
- `endswith` does not accept regular expressions

Comment: I believe endswith does accept regular expressions from what i read online and that was why I wrote it the way I did but obviously there is something wrong

Comment: @rose: Python allows you to try various expressions one by one. Start `python` (to get the interactive console), type `help(''.endswith)`, and try a few things.

Comment: @Sebastian thank you. I will try that and post how I fare